# Hibernate select query taking much time to execute with very less data

Tags: java, hibernate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDhtJ.png)
Schema and mapping

Below is the code I am using to fetch the data using hibernate.

```
DictionaryType dictType = DictionaryTypeRepo.findByName("STATISTICS");
Iterable<Dictionary> dict = DictionaryRepo.findAllByDictonaryType(dictType);
Iterable<Session> sessions = SessionRepo.findAllByDictionaryIn(dict);
```

In first query I am fetch single records based on the name.
In seconds query I am fetching multiple records based on the result of first query.
In third query I am fetching multiple records based on the result of second query.

I have used `ManyToOne` mapping and `FetchType.EAGER`.

All these queries taking almost 9 seconds to execute with almost 100 records in the table.
Could any one suggest what I am doing wrong while creating model class or while doing mapping ?

Comment: If it's a speed issue, you should check your query.  
`hibernate.show_sql=true`

Comment: I did that and it is showing 3 queries which seems ok.

Comment: Did you try with `Lazy` fetch instead of `Eager` fetch? so it will help you to understand that where is the actual delay.

Comment: Yes, I tried that also but no major difference as data is very less.